# Star cluster next to Venus

Tags: amateur-observing

Recently Observed Venus with my 6.3 inch Telescope with 401x magnification and got super crisp images, but just beside the Venus I found a relatively dim and somewhat large star Cluster (couldn't tell the Venus actually affected the image with its light). Now what actually is the Cluster? Location - Chennai, India. Time of observation- 19:00

Comment: PLease provide the full date , and convert the observation time to Zulu.  With that info, any decent stellarium app should be able to ID the cluster for you.

Comment: M7 is somewhat nearby.  Is that it?

Comment: @James K I guess no, because I can actually see the Venus while observing it

Comment: @CarlWitthoft most readers don't even know what "Zulu" even means; questions using local times have always been fine here, as long as what "local" meant was included.

Comment: Question seems fine, has enough information, can be and has been answered, so **voting to leave open** No need to prevent/block others from answering as well.

Comment: @uhoh well then this is a good time to learn about GMT since that's a rather useful concept in astronomy (and many other fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to [in-the-sky.org/skymap.php](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) changed the location to Chennai and set the clock back two an evening days. I found Venus in the west, clicked on it so see it's RA and Dec

[image]

Found Wikipedia's page for the constellation [Ophiuchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiuchus), found the map, and put a red dot where Venus was.

It seems like M19 and M62 were to the East of Venus and M9 was north of it. You were looking at the Milky Way (there's the constellation Sagittarius to the west (left) so you can expect to see all kinds of interesting things there!

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ophiuchus_IAU.svg) modified/annotated.